# Balanced Payments - How to check if bank account exists using fingerprint

Tags: balanced-payments

The Balanced documentation (https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/resources/#testing-customer-identity-verification) briefly talks about the fingerprint value returned after performing an authenticated action on a user's Balanced bank account id (which has been generated using balanced.js and posted to the server).  I receive the fingerprint value after calling bank_account.associate_to_customer.  The fingerprint value, according to the docs, is used "to check if a card has already been tokenized."

**After associating this bank account to a customer, do I need to do another check using this fingerprint to ensure this bank account hasn't already been created with Balanced?  If so, how is this done?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Balanced you can actually tokenize the same funding instrument multiple times, however, each token can only be associated to a single customer. To check for the uniqueness of a funding instrument you would simply compare the fingerprints on your end (e.g. if two fingerprints are equal they represent the same funding instrument).